# passing labels in echart line graph

Tags: flask, vuejs2, axios

I have a line chart that gets data from the back end. I am able to plot the data but not the labels from the back end. This is my code:

```
import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs'
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    extends: Line,
    props: ["data"],
    methods: {
        getScore() {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/time',
              }).then((response) => {
              this.renderChart(
              {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        labels: response.data.score,   
                        label: 'Stream',
                        backgroundColor: "#42c9d5",
                        data:  response.data.score
                    }
                ]
            },
            {responsive: true, maintainApsectRatio: false}
        )
              })
                .catch((error) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                  console.error(error);
                });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getScore();
    }
}
```

because I am getting the data from the getScore method. how Can I get the labels from another method? Or do I need to send two json responses? Also how do I loop through the json responses inside the this.renderchart?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. For those interested I passed a list of of dictionaries from the back end:

```
@app.route('/time')
def timeData():
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}
    SCORES = []
    score = {}
    score["value"] = [23,38,12]
    score["date"] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    SCORES.append(score)

    response_object['score'] = SCORES
    return jsonify(response_object)
```

I then added ... before the date key value pair:

```
import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs'
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    extends: Line,
    props: ["data"],
    methods: {
        getScore() {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/time',
              }).then((response) => {
              this.renderChart(
              {

                labels: [...response.data.score[0].date],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Stream',
                        backgroundColor: "#42c9d5",
                        data:  response.data.score[0].value
                    }
                ]
            },
            {responsive: true, maintainApsectRatio: false}
        )
              })
                .catch((error) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                  console.error(error);
                });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getScore();
    }
```